# Winapi: programatically obtain path of special folder given its CLSID as string

Tags: winapi, clsid

Does Windows API offer any way to obtain a special folder path (i.e. My Documents), given its CLSID as string (i.e. ::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103})? Can this be done in any way? Also, it should be done with functions supported under Windows XP.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is that GUID? CLSIDs identify COM classes. Is that a known folder ID? Please elaborate.

Comment: I know, it is confusing to me too since CLSIDs identify COM classes as you said. It's a string that identifies a Windows special folder, there's a list of them here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/the-secret-behind-the-windows-7-godmode. If you paste that string in the run dialog (Ctrl+R) it will open "My Documents" folder. Windows is resolving it to a path in some way and i'd like to know how it can be done

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm developing a program that receives the path to a directory as parameter. Such path can be given as a full qualified path (i.e. "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Projects"), or using one of those guids (i.e.  "::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}\Projects"). If the path is provided in the second form, I need to be capable of translating it to its full path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental API you need for this is `SHParseDisplayName`. That will take the `::{GUID}` format path and convert it to a PIDL.

If the PIDL then has a string form (as your example does, since it resolves to the Documents folder), you can use `SHGetPathFromIDList` to convert it.

```
LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
if (SUCCEEDED(SHParseDisplayName(L"::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}", nullptr, &pidl, 0, nullptr)))
{
    wchar_t wchPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, wchPath)))
    {
        // string form of path is now in wchPath
    }
    ILFree(pidl);
}
```